# How do I print only the first 10 lines from a csv file using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm new to Python and I'm wanting to print only the first 10 lines of a huge csv file.

Here's my code so far that prints all of the lines in the csv file

```
import csv
with open('titanic.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['survived'], row['pclass'], row['name'], row['sex'], row['age'])
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just `break` after 10 lines.

```
import csv
with open('titanic.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for i,row in enumerate(reader):
        print(row['survived'], row['pclass'], row['name'], row['sex'], row['age'])
        if(i >= 9):
            break
```

Comment: Perfect, that does it! I also want to use , as a delimiter separating the output rows. How would do go about doing that?

Answer (score 19):

Use `itertools.islice`:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open('titanic.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in islice(reader, 10): # first 10 only
        print(row['survived'], row['pclass'], row['name'], row['sex'], row['age'])
```

While you're at it, you can also make use of `operator.itemgetter` to make the column getting a bit easier:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice
from operator import itemgetter

get_columns = itemgetter('survived', 'pclass', 'name', 'sex', 'age')

with open('titanic.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in islice(reader, 10): # first 10 only
        print(*get_columns(row))
```

Comment: IMHO `islice` is overkill when all one needs to do is count the rows read so far...

Comment: @martineau perhaps - but why go to the effort of doing that when you don't need to? It also isolates the logic to the `for` and if you ever then need to offset from the start or introduce stepping, then you're not introducing more logic to an `if` or doing modulus etc... (not to mention - using `islice` can obviously do its work at the C level in CPython)

Comment: `for i in range(10):` also isolates the logic and is written in C.

Answer (score 1):

Adrien El Zein's answer is enough for your question. However, if you think it's slightly confusing (I don't think so):

```
import csv
counter = 0

with open('titanic.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in enumerate(reader):
       print(row['survived'], row['pclass'], row['name'], row['sex'], row['age'])
       counter += 1
       if counter >= 9:
           break
```

All I did was rename the variable `i` to `counter`. Also, for an alternative loop:

```
import csv
counter = 0

with open('titanic.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in enumerate(reader):
       print(row['survived'], row['pclass'], row['name'], row['sex'], row['age'])
       while counter < 10:
           counter += 1
       else:
           break
```

I tried and tested the `while-else` loop using Python 3.4.3 (not sure which version you have) and can tell you that it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

To get top N lines from a csv file, with select fields

```
#for python 3
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
N=11 # to get 10 rows need use 10+1=11
fname='titanic.csv'
get_columns=itemgetter('survived', 'pclass', 'name', 'sex', 'age')

with open(fname,'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile.readlines()[0:N])
    [print(*get_columns(row)) for row in reader]

     # or for all fields : use [print(row)) for row in reader]
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this could help you

**Code :**

```
count = 0
rg = 10
with open('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/employee.csv','r') as csvdt:
  csv_rd = csv.reader(csvdt)
  for j in  csv_rd:
    if count < rg:
      print(j)
      count = count + 1
```